# Another way to check std::queue event?

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, queue, std

Well, I'm trying to work on some kind of **queue**. I have an **IO thread** that it's dedicated for popping data out of the std::queue but **the problem is that I'm using a Sleep()** in order to prevent 100% cpu constant checking. **And of course other threads which will add items to the std::queue.**

How could I make an **event** so that the thread is dormant and **only** initiates when the std::queue is NOT empty?

**IO Thread**

```
Sleep(100);
while (!myqueue.empty())
  {
     //process data FIFO
     myqueue.pop(); //pop out and continue
  }
```

Much appreciated, thank you! Oh and this is for c++11 or c++03 it doesn't matter - on Windows.

Comment: C++11 or not? If not, which OS?

Comment: It's called a semaphore...

Comment: The typical way to do this is with a [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). Anthony Williams goes over some of the details of such an implementation [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).

Comment: I strongly recommend you read up something on thread synchronization. It's rather difficult topic and your code will need significant changes to avoid all pitfalls. Because it's not just locking around the operations (`empty`, `pop`), it also means ordering them correctly and locking across the right operations together.

Comment: Like @Tony hints, driver->thread comms is usually performed by semaphore signaling.  Create the semaphore with zero count.  In your driver, push on an object, signal the semaphore.  In your thread, wait on the semaphore, pop an object.   Dump the Sleep() and look at MSDN for semaphore API's and Windows synchronization primitives.

Comment: Also, if you are queueing between one driver and one thread, you may want to use a queue class that is safe to use without locking, (this is quite possible within those constraints, but I don't know if std::queue is safe to use that way?).

Answer (score 8):

`std::queue` has **absolutely nothing to do with threads**. At all. Its `.empty()` member is not thread-safe (only reentrant)! The same applies to all it's other members. So multiple threads can use different queues whatever they like, but only one thread at a time can do anything at all with each instance.

C++11 or C++03 matters **a lot.** Because C++11 defines thread synchronization primitives, while C++03 does not and you have to use OS API.

In C++11 you would be interested in [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

In C++03 you would be interested in either [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/) (mostly compatible with C++11) [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In either case the `std::queue::push()` and `std::queue::pop()` themselves **must** be protected by a mutual exclusion. The `std::condition_variable` even forces you to use one ([`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)), in Windows API you'd use [Critical Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

On Windows, the C++11 classes are only available in Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8. With older compiler use Boost (the advantage is that it will be portable) or native API.

Answer (score 1):

You need a "condition variable". Whenever a thread puts something on the queue it "notifies" threads waiting on the condition variable. The thread that consumes events from the queue waits on the condition variable. It is asleep until someone notifies it via the condition variable.

Boost has a nice implementation: http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref

You are using a lock to make sure access to the queue is thread-safe, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to first look into how to use a thread safe queue, then perhaps think about using boost::condition signaling to provide more control.

here is an example of how you could build a thread safe queue:

```
#pragma once                                                                              
#include <queue>                                                                       

template<typename T>                                                                       
class thread_safe_queue                                                                    
{                                                                                          
    queue<T>   m_queue;                                                                    
    pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;                                                               
    pthread_cond_t  m_condv;                                                               

    public:                                                                                
    thread_safe_queue() {                                                                  
        pthread_mutex_init(&m_mutex, NULL);                                                
        pthread_cond_init(&m_condv, NULL);                                                 
    }                                                                                      
    ~thread_safe_queue() {                                                                 
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mutex);                                                   
        pthread_cond_destroy(&m_condv);                                                    
    }                                                                                      
    void push(T& item) {                                                                   
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);                                                      

        T itemcpy = std::move(item);                                                       
        m_queue.push(std::move(itemcpy));                                                  

        pthread_cond_signal(&m_condv);                                                     
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);                                                    
    }                                                                                      
    T pop() {                                                                              
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);                                                      
        while (m_queue.size() == 0) {                                                      
            pthread_cond_wait(&m_condv, &m_mutex);                                         
        }                                                                                  

        T& _item = m_queue.front();                                                        
        T itemcpy = std::move(_item);                                                      

        m_queue.pop();                                                                     
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);                                                    
        return itemcpy;                                                                    
    }                                                                                      
    int size() {                                                                           
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);                                                      
        int size = m_queue.size();                                                         
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);                                                    
        return size;                                                                       
    }                                                                                      
};
```

this is how you instantiate it :

```
thread_safe_queue<myclass> myqueue;
```

if you want to use event signaling then look into using boost::condition - fx. like this:

```
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

boost::mutex mtxWait;
boost::condition cndSignalQueueHasNewEntry;

bool WaitForQueueSignal(long milliseconds)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock mtxWaitLock(mtxWait);
    boost::posix_time::time_duration wait_duration =  boost::posix_time::milliseconds(milliseconds); // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html
    boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time()+wait_duration; // http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/condition-variable-spurious-wakes.html
    return cndSignalQueueHasNewEntry.timed_wait(mtxWait,timeout); // wait until signal notify_one or timeout
}
```

This is how you can signal

```
cndSignalQueueHasNewEntry.notify_one();
```

This is how you can wait for signal

```
bool bResult = WaitForQueueSignal(10000); // timeout after 10 seconds
```